# How can I contribute files to MediaStore (SDK 29) on Android 10 in Flutter?

Tags: android, file, flutter, path, storage

I want to save files to the Download folder used by Android as the default Downloads directory. I have found out that this should be possible by using [MediaStore.downloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Downloads), but I have no clue how to do that in flutter!
When using

```
List<Directory> android_dir =
        await getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.downloads);
    String android_path = android_dir[0].path;
```

from the path_provider package, I seem to get a path to my application-specific directory

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mediaconverter/files/Download/

which doesn't seem easily accessible by the user through file browser apps.

Since Android 10 is deprecating ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory from the ExtStorage package, I am trying to find a way to accomplish saving files which can easily be accessed by the users. This is the folder which I want to target:

[image: My intended directory destination]

How can I accomplish that? The files seem to be created in the above-mentioned directory, but I can't access them through other apps.

I'm relatively new to developing for Android, so sorry in advance for the probably stupid question ... I couldn't find an answer by reading other questions and googling :/

Comment: MediaStore support currently is active topic issue at Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57380

Answer (score 0):

Check out [path provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
Directory documentsdir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

This will give you a directory which is accessible.

Comment: I read the path_provider example up and down and can't seem to get a grasp on it, sorry ... Where in the file system (or rather in a native file browser app) can I find the directory provided by getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() ?

I can of course print the path, but I can't find the files in the UI on Android then!

Comment: Yeah it is harder to find the file on android ill look into it for you, I mainly use IOS

Comment: On iOS, it works perfectly using the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory, but on Android, the files don't seem to be accessible through the aquivalent of the Files App, hence my question and idea to use the public Downloads directory since this is easily findable by users...

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's `path_provider` API is experiencing problems (open issues) due to Android changes taking place for Android 10 and above. This should be fixed -

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783

For now, the most reliable way of getting iOS/Android `Download` directory via flutter seems to be this -

```
  String dir;
  if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    dir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/"; //not elegant, but it works
  }else if(Platform.isIOS) {
    dir = (await getDownloadsDirectory()).path;
  }
  print(dir);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it safe? `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` if one can access downloads then can access other folders under 0/ as well. and app directories mostly lies under  `../0/Android/` .