# Flutter/Dart: Saving an image file to "/storage/emulated/0/Picture/AppFolder/"

Tags: flutter, storage, android-storage

using

`final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Image get saved in

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_app/files/`

But I want to store it in `../0/Pictures/app_name/` so that it shows up in the gallery.

I looked up all over the www and couldn't figure out. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first extract the root Path from the returned location 
`rootPath` = `/storage/emulated/0/` 
than create the `Pictures` and `app_name` Directory (to avoid exception when the directory doesn't exist)
then save file in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app_name/`

here's a simple example to help you understand:

```
...

    Directory externalPath = (await getExternalStorageDirectory());
    String picturesDirName = "Pictures";
    String appNameDirName = "app_name";
    

// Splitting the externalPath
    List<String> externalPathList = externalPath.path.split('/');


// getting Position of 'Android'
    int posOfAndroidDir = externalPathList.indexOf('Android');

//Joining the List<Strings> to generate the rootPath with "/" at the end.
    String rootPath = externalPathList.sublist(0, posOfAndroidDir).join('/');
    rootPath+="/";

//Creating Pictures Directory (if not exist)
    Directory picturesDir = Directory(rootPath+picturesDirName+"/");
    if (!picturesDir.existsSync()) {
      //Creating Directory
      await picturesDir.create(recursive: true);
      //Directory Created
    } else {
      //Directory Already Existed
    }

//Creating "app_name" Directory (if not exist)
    Directory appNameDir = Directory(rootPath+picturesDirName+"/"+appNameDirName+"/");
    if (!appNameDir.existsSync()) {
      //Creating Directory
      await appNameDir.create(recursive: true);
      //Directory Created
    } else {
      //Directory Already Existed
    }
    
//Creating String varible to store the path where you want to save file.
    String fileSaveLocation = rootPath+picturesDirName+"/"+appNameDirName+"/";
// Or you can also use templates like this
    String fileSaveLocation2 = "$rootPath$picturesDirName/$appNameDirName/";
    
//Your File Path where you want to save you file.
    String filePath = fileSaveLocation+"text.txt";
// Or you can also use templates like this
    String filePath2 = "${fileSaveLocation2}test.txt";
...
```

You can optimize the above code as per your liking.

hope this is the solution you were looking.

Comment: Thanks for much detailed answer. This would help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Is how you can acheive this,

```
final Directory extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/app_name/pictures';
dirPath = dirPath.replaceAll("Android/data/com.example.flutter_app/files/", "");
await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
// start File Operations Here with dirPath variable
```

Comment: This is much precise. Though, I would need to switch added string to `/Pictures/app_name/`  in second line so to make `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app_name/`. Thanks.

Comment: if this solved your issue then you can close the question

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Along with detailed answer below, I came across a couple of plugins which deals specially with media content.

From [Flutter.dev docs](http://%20https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files):

> The plugin currently supports access to two file system locations:

1. [gallery_saver Plugin: See Full Example](https://github.com/CarnegieTechnologies/gallery_saver)

```
GallerySaver.saveImage(path).then((bool success) {// code }
```

2. [Image_gallery_saver: See Full Example](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)

```
await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.data), quality: 60, name: "hello");
```

3. Creating the path manually: [Source](https://retroportalstudio.medium.com/saving-files-to-application-folder-and-gallery-in-flutter-e9be2ebee92a)

```
await Permission.storage.request();
if (await Permission.storage.isGranted) {
  var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  Dio dio = Dio();
  var newPath = "";
  List<String> paths = dir.path.split("/");
  for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
      String folder = paths[x];
      if (folder != "Android") {
          newPath += "/" + folder;
        } 
      else {
          break;
      }
  }
  var picfolder = "/Pictures/";
  newPath = newPath + picfolder + AppStrings['AppName'];
```

**Other Useful References:**
[Android Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)
[MediaStore in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835490/how-can-i-contribute-files-to-mediastore-sdk-29-on-android-10-in-flutter)

Comment: A weird bug in SO editor, I couldn't add one more link.
Here it is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797617/saving-photo-in-flutter-esp-to-camera-roll